# Getting reference of datatable row from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below which deletes the current row of the datatable. This code is located in a js file and the js file is referenced in the html file where the table resides.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#orders', "td .fa.fa-minus-square", function () {       
    //get the description from the column whose class="description"
    var description = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text();
   //get the reference 
    var removeItemEl = $(this);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line item?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $.ajax({    
                url: "/api/mycontroller?description=" + description,
                method: "DELETE",
                success: function () {
                    table.row(removeItemEl.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem here is that the $(this) reference does not refer to anything. If I move this code back to the html file then it works fine. How do I access the row on which this button resides?

Comment: Please show your html, it might help in giving you the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this everywhere  with $(event.target), but also add event as function argument in first line.

```
...function (event) ...
....

var description = $(event.target)
if ($(event.target) != //--insert desired element here

    //cancel event handling if source is not desired element
    return;

//source is desired element

....
```

Comment: This solution will trigger when anything in that row is clicked. I want it to trigger only when the delete button is clicked.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: add limiting options inside function or change selectors, I will add a rough example

Comment: With current code (just a rough example) you can cancel event handling if source is not your desired element